# what is the 'extra' mean in this django code

Tags: python, sql, django

```
TOPIC_COUNT_SQL = """
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM topics_topic
WHERE
    topics_topic.object_id = maps_map.id AND
    topics_topic.content_type_id = %s
"""
MEMBER_COUNT_SQL = """
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM maps_map_members
WHERE maps_map_members.map_id = maps_map.id
"""

maps = maps.extra(select=SortedDict([
    ('member_count', MEMBER_COUNT_SQL),
    ('topic_count', TOPIC_COUNT_SQL),
]), select_params=(content_type.id,))
```

i don't know this mean,

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [method of `QuerySet`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra-select-none-where-none-params-none-tables-none-order-by-none-select-params-none).